# Is there a clean way to convert runtime values to compile time values?

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a type with non-type parameters based on run-time values, the `make_fruit` function:

```
struct IFruit {
    // interface
};

enum Species {
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Peach,
};

enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Yellow,
};

template <Species S, Color C> struct Fruit : public IFruit {
    // impl
};

IFruit* make_fruit(Species s, Color c) {
    // return new Fruit<s, c>
}
```

Is there a clean way to do it? As in, not writing 12 switch cases.

Edit: note: the classes `IFruit`, `Fruit` and enums `Color`, `Species` are given (by some library) and cannot be modified.

Comment: Maybe `S` and `C` don't need to be template parameters.  Just pass them in to the constructor of the `Fruit` object when you create a `Fruit` object, and store them as member variables.  Then the code in `make_fruit` becomes basically `Fruit(s, c)` and no switch statement is needed.

Comment: You need to create the mapping of template arguments to factory function yourself.

Comment: Added info, the (I)Fruit classes and the enums are in some giant library and cannot be modified

Comment: You can always use data instead of code and have a nested array or map of enum,enum -> factory entries, and then simply say `return fac[s][c]();`. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid to write the combinatory yourself thanks to [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) of [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (both C++17):

```
using SpeciesVariant = std::variant<
        std::integral_constant<Species, Species::Apple>,
        std::integral_constant<Species, Species::Orange>,
        std::integral_constant<Species, Species::Peach>
    >;

using ColorVariant = std::variant<
        std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Red>,
        std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Green>,
        std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Blue>,
        std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Yellow>
    >;

SpeciesVariant to_variant(Species s)
{
    switch (s) {
        case Species::Apple: return std::integral_constant<Species, Species::Apple>{};
        case Species::Orange: return std::integral_constant<Species, Species::Orange>{};
        case Species::Peach: return std::integral_constant<Species, Species::Peach>{};
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Bad argument");
}

ColorVariant to_variant(Color c)
{
    switch (c) {
        case Color::Red: return std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Red>{};
        case Color::Green: return std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Green>{};
        case Color::Blue: return std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Blue>{};
        case Color::Yellow: return std::integral_constant<Color, Color::Yellow>{};
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Bad argument");
}
```

and finally:

```
std::unique_ptr<IFruit> make_fruit(Species s, Color c)
{
    return std::visit([](auto s, auto c) -> std::unique_ptr<IFruit> {
            return std::make_unique<Fruit<s, c>>();
        }, to_variant(s), to_variant(c));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Wx14f733)

Comment: I have to go through hours of materials to understand how this works. But now I do! A very composable solution.

Comment: If you don't have access to c++17, LaurentJospin's solution would be similar (less composable, but avoid extra dynamic dispatch involved by `std::visit`)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No!

Long answer: Still no, but you can make you life easier by creating intermediate nested functions. Each function is templated for the enums you already treated and have a switch for a single enum. So instead of writing 12 condition, you would write only 7 in your case, and the more values exists, the more you'll save with this approach.

```
template <Species s> 
IFruit* make_fruit_of_species(Color c) {
     //your switch for color here
}

IFruit* make_fruit(Species s, Color c) {
    // your switch for species here, returning a value with make_fruit_of_species
}
```

But I wonder if you really need a template for such a simple case. Maybe you just need a member of type species and one of type color.

Comment: Thanks! This indeed saves some typing. The real-life library has 4 non-type template parameters, a total of 100+ combinations, driving me crazy!